# Disbling Visual C++ compiler while using Intel in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mlpack

I am trying to build mlpack in Visual Studio 2010 using Intel compiler. There are many statements like

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
  #if (_MSC_VER < 1700)
    #error "*** Need a newer compiler ***"
  #endif
```

This is throwing an error. However, this should not be an issue as I am using Intel compiler. How should I make `#if defined(_MSC_VER)` to false?

There are many places which has this code so uncommenting them manually is not an option.

Comment: Can you manually set `_MSC_VER` to be 1700 or higher?

Comment: There are multiple projects. Don't know how to set it globally

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/523253

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think that's what I've been looking for